# Authorization and ACL in cakephp 3

Tags: authorization, acl, cakephp-3.0

I search the document but I don't find anything about ACL implementation in cakephp 3.
How can I implement authorization with ACL in cakephp 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ACL is not built into CakePHP 3 as it was in CakePHP 2. It is now available as a separate plugin.

> *Quote from http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html*
>
> ACL related classes were moved to a separate plugin. Password hashers,
> Authentication and Authorization providers where moved to the
> \Cake\Auth namespace. You are required to move your providers and
> hashers to the App\Auth namespace as well.

You can find the plugin at https://github.com/cakephp/acl, but note that it's not yet stable.

Answer (score 3):

Great question, as Daniel Castro said the plugin is at https://github.com/cakephp/acl.

The part that is missing is to override 'isAuthorized' in your 'AppController.php' with something like:

```
...
use Acl\Controller\Component\AclComponent;
use Cake\Controller\ComponentRegistry;
...



public function isAuthorized($user){
      $Collection = new ComponentRegistry();
      $acl= new AclComponent($Collection);
      $username=$user['username'];
      $controller=$this->request->controller;
      $action=$this->request->action;
      $check=$acl->check($user['username'],"$controller/$action");
      return $check;
    }
```

Someone wiser than I will know better if the  user/action/controller bits could be better sanitized.  There are lots of warnings about the stability of this plugin and 'gotchas' on acl in terms of performance.

I am cutting over from a 1.3 implementation, it was helpful to add in the AppController 'initialize' info from http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html