# show and hide buttons/links based on ACL in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0, acl

I want to hide the button/link based on ACO. Please help me how to do it in cakephp 3 as for cakephp2 we can do it by follow [this](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html) link.

I need alternative of following for cakephp3:

```
public function index() {
// These all return true:
$this->Acl->check('warriors/Aragorn', 'Weapons');
$this->Acl->check('warriors/Aragorn', 'Weapons', 'create');
$this->Acl->check('warriors/Aragorn', 'Weapons', 'read');
}
```

Comment: Cakephp 3 does not have ACL.  This link might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728798/authorization-and-acl-in-cakephp-3

Comment: Yes, I followed the solution from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728798/authorization-and-acl-in-cakephp-3). Now i getting following error:
Warning (512): DbAcl::check() - Failed ARO node lookup in permissions check. Node references:
Aro: admin/admin
Aco: Users [ROOT\vendor\cakephp\acl\src\Model\Table\PermissionsTable.php, line 76]

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049637/dbaclcheck-failed-aro-aco-node-lookup-in-permissions-check